# PHP str_replace at the URL

Tags: php

I want to remove "&start=2" from a given URL.
This is what I tried:

```
$uri = "http://test.com/test/?q=Marketing&start=2";

$newuri = str_replace("&start=","",$url);

echo $newuri;
```

Comment: Please can you put your question a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to use `preg_replace` instead for this:

```
$newuri = preg_replace('/&start=(\d+)/','',$uri);
```

Comment: It's unnecessary to capture the \d+ in parentheses

Comment: Right... but it helps from a readability standpoint. Not critical in this example, but it's good practice for when gigantic regex patterns come around.

Comment: As the asker is a beginner, perhaps a little more elaboration as to what the code is doing?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing $url as an argument to str_replace. But the variable that has the url is called $uri.

```
$uri = "http://test.com/test/?q=Marketing&start=2";

$newuri = str_replace("&start=2","",$uri);

...
```

Comment: This won't actually remove the numeric value `2` of `start` as the OP requires. A generic solution allowing for arbitrary numbers would need a regular expression replacement function.

Comment: Fixed. Now it removes the value 2 without using regex.

Comment: What if they have **3** instead of **2**?

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw a regex-free solution out there:

```
// Grab the individual components of the URL
$uri_components = parse_url($uri); 

// Take the query string from the url, break out the key:value pairs
// then put the keys and values into an associative array
foreach (explode('&', $uri_components['query']) as $pair) {
    list($key,$value) = explode('=', $pair);
    $query_params[$key] = $value;
}

// Remove the 'start' pair from the array and start reassembling the query string
unset($query_params['start']);
foreach ($query_params as $key=>$value)
    $value ? $new_query_params[] = $key."=".$value : $new_query_params[] = $key;

// Now reassemble the whole URL (including the bits removed by parse_url)
$uri_components['scheme'] .= "://";
$uri_components['query'] = "?".implode($new_query_params,"&");
$newuri = implode($uri_components);
```

Admittedly it's massively verbose compared to the regex-based solutions, but it might provide some extra flexibility down the line?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that it is still a valid URI if the position of the querystring elements is changed. So the `start` parameter may be the first, hence it may be preceded by a `?` instead of a `&`.

So this regex covers both cases:

`preg_replace("#[\?&]start=\d+#", '', $uri)`

Answer (score 0):

Try This regex free solution:

```
$uri = "http://test.com/test/?q=Marketing&start=2";
$QueryPos = strpos($uri, '&start='); //find the position of '&start='
$newURI = substr($uri, 0, -(strlen($uri)-$QueryPos)); //remove everything from the start of $QueryPos to end
echo $newURI; //OUTPUT: http://test.com/test/?q=Marketing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['start']))

{

   $pageNo = $_GET['start'];

   $TmpString = '&start='.$pageNo;

  $newuri = str_replace($TmpString,"",$url);

  // removed "&start=2"

  echo $newuri;

}
```